# How to speed up the initial use of `helm-M-x`?

Tags: helm, spacemacs

When I run `helm-M-x` (`SPC :`) in Spacemacs, the first time is slow in loading/showing. Is there a way to "preload" it during startup/.spacemacs?

Answer (score 3):

This requires an understanding of `autoload`, `require`, `provide`, and "named features". A brief introduction to those concepts is at: [Spacemacs Layers](http://spacemacs.org/doc/LAYERS.html).

1. Find out which "named feature" `helm-M-x` is in. One way: look at the source code of the file and try to find `(provide 'xxxx)`. In this case, it is `'helm-command` (source: [helm-command.el](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-command.el))
2. Use `(require 'helm-command)` in your init/startup configuration after all other layers/packages have been loaded (eg `dotspacemacs/user-config`).